# Google Analytics - Failed to load resource: http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js

Tags: google-analytics, http-status-code-404

I've been noticing this error on Chrome's console for a while now:

[image]

I modified Google's script so that it logs the error, because it uses `try{} catch{}`, and this is what I got:

[image]

I haven't noticed *considerable* changes in the stats, it's always in ups and downs.

Also, this isn't only on my sites, but fricking everywhere. I haven't found bug reports or anything like that.

If I go to http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js on the browser, it loads normally.

Does anyone have a clue of what causes this?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy or firewall?

Comment: What happens if you try to directly open [http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js](http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js) in a browser? It sounds like you might be blocking or redirecting google-analytics.com in a local HOSTS file.

Comment: Check that you're not using AdBlock or something that may be blocking loading Google Analytics.

Comment: Yes. I disabled AdBlock and now it loads it fine. Didn't think of that, thank you :)

Comment: I had this problem using an VPN, turning it off removed the issue.

Comment: Other users using ABP will still block your data from being sent. I have mocked up a workaround here: http://kennystechtalk.blogspot.com/2016/03/adblockanalytics.html

Answer (score 197, accepted):

It was a problem with AdBlock. I disabled it and now it loads it normally.

**yagudaev** suggests (read answers below) that in order to keep AdBlock from blocking Google Analytics, you need to edit the snippet provided and explicitly use `https://` instead of the protocol-relative URL by default. This means changing

`'//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'`

into

`'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'`

Example:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-XX', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: Same here. It makes you feel so silly when something like this happens. I remember spending half a day fixing some image not downloading from the server, only to realise that having named it 'banner.jpg' made AdBlock block it as well. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yet they allow ads in Gmail, WTF AdBlock, WTF

Comment: I used http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm file to do my adblocking and thought GA changed their setup because I couldn't access anything from the domain. whooops.

Comment: Does it mean that GA dont count people with Addblock?

Comment: @AdamPietrasiak Yes, it does mean unfortunately. :( Some regional filer list contains rules which are completely blocking the GA, GTM and all awesome Google stuff... even the MVT test (A/B tests) won't work if you use experiment in GA. I cannot understand why is good for the people (eventually the filer list maintainers)... A common user won't configure the white list and any other settings... they will just install the plugin and that's it... and we are just loosing the data in stats.

Comment: It was the [ghostery extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghostery/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij) for me... whitelisting works

Comment: This will have no effect whatsoever. The domain is blocked so changing the protocol is aimless.

Comment: indeed Ken, unfortunately for me even though I changed the http to https I can still see this in debug console of the browser (chrome + adBlock plus):

GET https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: @Ovi-WanKenobi did you try the the white filter suggestion? `@@|http://www.google-analytics.com`

Comment: For any others - I was seeing a similar issue, but it wasn't because of Adblock, it was my Avast security extension. I viewed my site with another browser (or view in Incognito) which didn't have any plugins and no errors!

Answer (score 8):

It could also be your hosts file, here's mine:

```
$ grep -ni "google-analytics.com" /etc/hosts
6203:# 127.0.0.1  ssl.google-analytics.com #[disabled = Firefox issues]
6204:127.0.0.1  www.google-analytics.com #[Google Analytics]
```

Comment: That was it. No idea how it got in there to begin with, but removing it worked.

Answer (score 4):

If it's an offline app (ie, you've defined a cache manifest) be sure to allow the network request.

See [HTML5 Appcache causing problems with Google Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410974/html5-appcache-causing-problems-with-google-analytics)

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are running into problems is because AdBlock will block this script if and only if it does not go through `https`. Notice the error you get it contains an `http:` protocol reference.

All you need to do is change the snippet to force it to go through an ssl connection by adding an explicit protocol instead of the protocol relative url that is the default.

```html
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-XX', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: That's actually a good tip to avoid losing stats on users who use AdBlock. Since there already is an accepted answer, I'll add your tip to it. Thanks!

Comment: https makes no difference at all. The host is blocked, not the URL.

Comment: indeed Ken, unfortunately for me even though I changed the http to https I can still see this in debug console of the browser:

GET https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Answer (score 2):

This error is commonly caused due to one of [*the extensions installed*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50151073/4058484) within Chrome.
There are a few ways to debug and solve an ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT message.

> - Disable the extension.
> - Whitelist the domain.
> - Debug the issue.

I would recommend to find more detail at [*How to Solve ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT*](https://www.keycdn.com/support/how-to-solve-err-blocked-by-client/)

Comment: I was using Disconnect extension for Firefox and when I whitelisted the domain it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**2019 update**

This has become very widespread now.

**Solutions**

1. Ask people to unblock your website, (bad idea from personal experience)
2. Host google analytics script locally (bad idea) because google says so [HERE](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032389?hl=en)

> Referencing the JavaScript file from Google's servers (i.e.,
>   https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js) ensures that you get access
>   to new features and product updates as they become available, giving
>   you the most accurate data in your reports.

3. Use Server side analytics. This is what people are doing nowadays. If you are on node.js, use a library such as [analytics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/analytics) or [universal-analytics](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-analytics)

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed same thing on my browser some time ago. 
Did you sing in to chrome using your Google account maybe? Or did you choose in any way to opt-out from collecting data on Google Analytics ?

Maybe Google remembers that option and uses it on Chrome when you are singed in..

BTW. I can normally open http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js in browser, it just doesn't work when automatically loaded.

Comment: It was a problem with AdBlock. I disabled it and now it loads it normally.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (or similar proxy) is not active.

Comment: Windscribe also blocks Google Analytics.