# HTML5 Appcache causing problems with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics

I have an [appcache](http://ilanshomekitchen.x10.mx/) file on my website which looks like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# V1.691 1-18-2013 10:57 PM

# cache 

index.html
about.html
services.html
contact.html
css/signika.css
css/mq.css
css/index.css
css/about.css
css/services.css
css/contact.css
assets/signika_400.woff    
assets/signika_600.woff
js/jquery.js
js/html5.js
js/index.js
js/mq.js
js/services.js
mail.php
images/chicken.png
images/salad.png
images/soup.png
images/steak.png
images/wontons.png

# network

https://google-analytics.com/ga.js
```

I feel like this is causing a conflict with the google analytics file that is being retrieved...but I don't know how.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the `CACHE:` header and `NETWORK:` header, like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# V1.691 1-18-2013 10:57 PM

# cache
CACHE:

index.html
about.html
...
images/steak.png
images/wontons.png

# network
NETWORK:

https://google-analytics.com/ga.js
```

The lines beginning with `#` are comments, and thus are ignored.

For further information, checkout [the wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_manifest_in_HTML5) or [this tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) about **HTML5 cache manifest**.

Comment: It seems that I forgot to add in the actual section title after the comment, thanks for pointing that out. I'm just double checking to make sure every browser is good with it now.

Comment: Hey Pang, it seems that my issue of Google Analytics and now a google voice call widget in the NETWORK section aren't being retrieved properly, any idea why?

Comment: any ideas because I have none.

Comment: I made a new question because you didn't answer my comment..and it is somewhat different from my original problem.

Answer (score 2):

The cache manifest specification allows wildcards under the "NETWORK:" heading. This code will allow http: or https: to work properly as well as the gif file that actually gets retrieved and does the tracking.

```
NETWORK:
*
```

I initially added the ga.js to my CACHE: and kept on getting an error retrieving the gif file, until I added the code above.