# I am getting Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT with Google chrome

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, ads, adsense

I am getting white page after running my project but its work with .net Client properly Do I need any settings in the browser?
and the link will come after the error

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT http://clkmon.com/adServe/getTag?cid=200093510300000000&pid=CRSRDR&type=inject

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT http://ads.626apps.com/a.php?626ref2=200093510300000000&626Name=Plus-HD-4.9&626ref3=B41A77C1675040A28F7E209964620E5EIE&626ref1=63726f73737269646572
```

Comment: See my answer below - Avoid using words like "advert" or "advertise" in your scripts, as Adblocking software assume its use and block it from browsers!  Not good if you are the programmer wanting your full page content to be shown.

Comment: If it did the trick, you should mark Martin Sansone answer as accepted.

Comment: Yes. Its the Ad Blocker.

Comment: I wrote a blog post and video about this https://love2dev.com/blog/what-the-heck-does-neterr_blocked_by_client-mean-and-how-can-you-fix-it/

Answer (score 702):

These errors are usually generated from an ad blocking plugin, such as Adblock Plus. To test this use either a different browser or uninstall the ad blocking plugin (right clicking the extension by the URL bar and clicking "Remove from Chrome...").

There is an easier way to temporarily disable an extension. In Chrome, opening an Incognito tab will usually stop extensions running (unless you have specifically told Chrome which ones to run in Incognito).

Comment: On a page I had created locally, adblock was still interfering, disabled it for localhost from now on.

Comment: I was getting this issue for several sites, and I resolved it by changing my Privacy Badger extension's settings for the sites in question.

Comment: For me it was Privacy Badger (from the EFF)

Comment: Another example: Ghostery.

Comment: Why would uninstalling the adblock plugin ever be the solution?

Comment: You won't believe what a headache you have just solved. Ta!

Comment: For me it was Avira Browser Safety 1.12.1 - that also blocks google analytics

Comment: Thank you for solving the puzzle, I would have never guessed the ad blocker caused this trouble.

Comment: DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials extension will block it.

Comment: Windscribe also blocks resources

Comment: I was using Pluckeye Extension and it was doing the same.

Comment: In my case I was getting this error because I was using Brave browser that does have a native ad blocker so I just switch to Firefox to run the tests and it was all ok

Comment: Brave will naturally do this! You will have to disable its "Brave Shield" for your specific site.

Answer (score 79):

My advice is to avoid any image names; class names or ID's with the words:

- Advert
- Advertise

in their name!

I ran some tests and Ad blockers regularly block any direct content with these names either within the CSS file, Div or Span Layers.

So an image name loaded via CSS such as **advertise-with-us.png**  gets blocked on any machine running such software for example.

**EDIT:**  I've Traced a list of web page elements in Chrome which AdBlock Plus sets the CSS value to "display:none". They probably apply to other browsers too:

```
::content #ads > .dose > .dosesingle, 
::content #content > #center > .dose > .dosesingle,
::content #content > #right > .dose > .dosesingle, 
::content #header + #content > #left > #rlblock_left, 
::content .trc_rbox_border_elm .syndicatedItem, 
::content .trc_rbox_div .syndicatedItem, 
::content div[id^="mainads"], ::content #ad-banner-980, 
::content #adbox300600, ::content #chartAdWrap, 
::content #in-content-ad, ::content #main-right-ad-tray, 
::content #second-right-ad-tray, ::content #sponsored-message, 
::content #tr-adv-banner, ::content #votvAds_inner, 
::content #welcome_ad, ::content #wp_ad_marker, 
::content .PremiumObitAdBar, ::content .ad-active
```

Comment: this must be it.  I'm developing a rails app with a advert controller.  it generates an empty adverts.js.coffee and adblock plus is blocking it, even though it is empty.

Comment: Yep! I'd expect it would be blocked.  Glad that I could help :)  -   Annoying as it is, as a rudimentary Adblock script would 'assume' with the word "advert" in it that its showing unwanted ads !!!  Programmers tasked with including external ad scripting are just going to use arbitrary id names to get around the current Ad blockers.

Comment: ``banners`` in the URL of a Ajax call is also blocked by AdBlock Plus.

Comment: Ad-Gallery !  Anybody using Ad-Gallery slider will also find assets  which genuinely use element names starting "ad-" will also go astray on web pages with AdBlock Plus enabled.  Prev & Next buttons  as well as active thumb image will all disappear !! -  Change the element names within the jquery.ad-gallery.js file to avoid this.

Comment: I would advise not to use advertisements.

Answer (score 29):

There are two steps here: troubleshooting and then fixing the issue:

- To troubleshoot, check to see if it is a browser and/or extension problem. Chrome, Firefox and others have incognito or private mode which does not load extensions or the basic database of passwords and cookies.
- In the case of ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT that is usually some kind of blocking software, such as Adblock, Ghostery, or some other kind of privacy/anti-spyware tool.

Comment: Just installed uBlock, this was my issue! Thanks so much

Comment: Just installed AdBlock, this was my issue! Thanks so much

Comment: In my case was ghostery blocking the elastic beanstalk tracker.

Comment: AdBlock was my issue too!

Answer (score 21):

Don't use keyworks like "ad", "ads", "advertise", etc. in image url or image class.
Adblock block them automatically.

Comment: ours was blocked because the path of the image included /banner/

Comment: thanks for your time, my route like that

Answer (score 19):

If you are running multiple extensions that perform ad or script blocking you will need to

> *individually update each one to your **whitelist***

Taking from *[this source](https://www.wired.com/whitelist-wired/)*, here are some of the extensions that may cause the case and how to deal with them.

**Adblock Plus**

- Click the Adblock Plus icon.
- Click “Enabled on this site” to disable ad blocking for the current
  site.
- In Firefox Click “disable on wired.com” to disable ad blocking.
- Reload the page you were viewing.
- If problem still persist, cek if the character string "-300x600" is in the file name, that particular text pattern  [*matches an expression list pattern in the AdBlock Plus*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50152891/4058484).

**Firefox Tracking Protection**

- In Firefox “Tracking Protection” may activate our adblock notice. It
  can be temporarily disabled for a browsing session by clicking the
  “shield” icon in the url bar if visible and following the
  instructions.
- For further details on Tracking Protection please review Mozilla’s
  support.

**Adblock**

- Click the Ad Block icon.
- Click “Don’t run on pages on this domain”.
- Reload the page you were viewing.

**Ghostery**

- Click the Ghostery icon.
- In Ghostery versions < 6.0 Click “Whitelist site”.
- In Ghostery version 7.0 click “trust site”
- In Versions < 6.0 You will see the message “Site is whitelisted”.
  Click “reload the page to see your changes.”
- Reload the page you were viewing.

**uBlock / uBlock Origin**

- Click the uBlock / uBlock Origin icon.
- Click the “power” button in the menu that appears to whitelist the
  current web site.
- Click the reload icon to reload the page you were viewing.

**Disconnect**

- Click the Disconnect icon.
- Click “Whitelist site”.

**Kaspersky Ant-Banner**
Please review How to configure Anti-Banner in Kaspersky Total Security for information on how to whitelist with Kaspersky Total Security.

Answer (score 6):

As other people have mentioned, this issue is common when using adblock or similar extensions.

The source of my issues was my [Privacy Badger](https://www.eff.org/privacybadger) extension.

Answer (score 6):

I noticed the same error as soon as I added Google Analytics and started testing on localhost.

I have both AdBlock as well as Ghostery... it actually (for me) wasn't AdBlock interfering - it was Ghostery. To "fix", in Ghostery settings, under "Analytics", uncheck Google Analytics.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just run chrome in incognito mode, that automatically switches off all your plugins/extensions, including any add blockers.  Then you can quickly see if the extensions are causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This issue may be due to the flags of chrome browser. Reset it, it worked for me.
chrome://flags
Right corner 'Reset all to defaults' button.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the similar error, it is basically caused when use the ad blockers.Turn them off, and you run it easily.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, also seeing "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED" and "ILLEGAL TOKEN" errors when loading JS files locally.  Pressing CTRL+SHIFT+DEL and deleting all "Cookies and other site and plugin data" and "Cached images and files" fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

My browser is Edge and I was not using any adblocker. For me the problem was using having the "Tracking prevention" setting in the browser set to "strict".

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need to disable extensions and retry the page to see if errors reoccur. If not, then the culprit might be one (or more) of them.

On my own case it was a deprecated switch, I've set up long ago. I used process-per-tab which was getting phased-out in recent (48-53) versions. Once I removed that switch all started to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late to the party... but I found this as a solution for me when having "blocked"-Error in chrome:

> Blocking resources whose URLs contain both `\n` and `<` characters.

More info here: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5735596811091968

Answer (score 0):

for chrome open cache. dev -> network -> disable to enable

Answer (score 0):

In my case it case the name of the file. I had it as "popup2.js" and it was being blocked. As soon as I changed it to "popap.js" (I had already a "popup.js" file) it started working

Answer (score 0):

I had this error in Brave, but not in Edge.  Probably I could add this site to the Brave  whitelist, but I rather use Edge for some things and Brave for others.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on Chrome. In my case, I was using Internet Download Manager chrome extension. Disabling it fixed the issue.