# Firefox jquery ajax JSONP call not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, jsonp

I'm trying to get a JSONP `$.ajax` request working. It works fine in Chrome and IE but it is failing in Firefox v30.

When it fails it doesn't given any error - at least Firebug doesn't show any errors, it just never calls the callback function.

This is a basic demo site (http://andysylvester.com/files/reader/) will work with Chrome and IE but not Firefox.

The nytRiver.js JSON call actually returns a javascript function call to `onGetRiverStream` see the documentation here: http://riverjs.org/#structureOfRiverjs

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Minimal River.js Feed Reader</title>
        <script src="http://fargo.io/code/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var theRiver;
            function onGetRiverStream (updatedFeeds) {
                theRiver = updatedFeeds;
        displayFeeds();
                }
            $.ajax ({ 
                url: "http://rss.scripting.com/rivers/nytRiver.js",  
                dataType: "jsonp"
                });
      function displayFeeds() {
        var feedText = "";
        // Create title
        for (var i in theRiver.updatedFeeds.updatedFeed) {
           feedText = feedText + theRiver.updatedFeeds.updatedFeed[i].feedTitle + " <a href=" + theRiver.updatedFeeds.updatedFeed[i].feedUrl + "> (Feed) " + "</a><br>"; 
           feedText = feedText + "<a href=" + theRiver.updatedFeeds.updatedFeed[i].item[0].link + ">" + theRiver.updatedFeeds.updatedFeed[i].item[0].title + "</a><br>"; 
           feedText = feedText + theRiver.updatedFeeds.updatedFeed[i].item[0].body + "<br>"; 
           feedText = feedText + "<br>";
        }
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = feedText; 
      }
            </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <h1><center>Minimal River.js Feed Reader</center></h1>
    <p id="demo">Wating for feeds to load....</p> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: load it a a script url, not as json or ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a Firefox add-on [Privacy Badger](https://www.eff.org/privacybadger). It was blocking rss.scripting.com as a 3rd party tracker.

I have the same add-on installed for Google Chrome - although in the beginning it was not blocking rss.scripting.com. However once it did block it then Chrome debugging tools manage to better Firebug and it gives the following error:

`net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

A quick SO search brings up this answer: [I am getting Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT with Google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318119/i-am-getting-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-blocked-by-client-with-google-chr)

That implies that its an ad-blocking add-on causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function() {

    onGetRiverStream = function (updatedFeeds) {
                theRiver = updatedFeeds;
                displayFeeds();
                };

    displayFeeds = function() {
        var feedText = "";
        // Create title
        for (var i in theRiver.updatedFeeds.updatedFeed) {
           feedText = feedText + theRiver.updatedFeeds.updatedFeed[i].feedTitle + " <a href=" + theRiver.updatedFeeds.updatedFeed[i].feedUrl + "> (Feed) " + "</a><br>"; 
           feedText = feedText + "<a href=" + theRiver.updatedFeeds.updatedFeed[i].item[0].link + ">" + theRiver.updatedFeeds.updatedFeed[i].item[0].title + "</a><br>"; 
           feedText = feedText + theRiver.updatedFeeds.updatedFeed[i].item[0].body + "<br>"; 
           feedText = feedText + "<br>";
        }
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = feedText; 
      };

  $.getScript("http://rss.scripting.com/rivers/nytRiver.js");

});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/T7cZL/

See [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: thanks for this, the problem was completely unreleated though. I found the problem which is the Privacy Badger Firefox add-on that I have installed - it was blocking rss.scripting.com as a 3rd party tracker!