# url rerouting gives blank page in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

This is my code ...when i am running program i am getting blank page
i checked URL routing i dont know where is the mistake. plese find the mistake and tell me.

This is main page.
   Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="starter">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title></title>
        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
      </body>
    </html>
```

This is my script page 
App.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('event', {
      url: "/event",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/side-menu.html",
      controller:'MainCtrl'
    })
    .state('event.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('event.profile', {
      url: "/profile",
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/profile.html"
        }
      }
    })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/event");
})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
  $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };
})
```

This is my side-menu page
side-menu.html

```
<ion-side-menus>
        <ion-side-menu-content> 
          <ion-header-bar id="header" class="bar-positive">
                <button menu-toggle="left" ng-click = "toggleLeft()" class = "button button-icon icon ion-navicon-round"></button>
                <ul id="header-right">
                  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span></li>
                  <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></li>
                </ul>
          </ion-header-bar>
          <div class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-positive tabs-color-light">
            <div class="tabs" id="tabs">
              <a class="tab-item" href="#">
                 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i>
              </a>
              <a class="tab-item" href="#">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></i>
              </a>
              <a class="tab-item" href="#">
               <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>
              </a>
              <a class="tab-item" href="#">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </ion-side-menu-content>
         <ion-side-menu side="left">
          <ion-header-bar class="bar-energized">
            <h2 class="title">settings</h4>
          </ion-header-bar>  

          <ion-content  class="left-menu">
            <ul class="list">
              <a href="#/event/home" class="item" menu-close>home</a>
              <a href="#/event/profile" class="item" menu-close>profile</a>
            </ul>
          </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: please answer my question

Comment: Could you share the error! go to chrome f12 for developers view and share the console error. If local debugging

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/ for more information

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
product_page.js:1 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
http://dial.clickscart.in/js/ads.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: basically, your ads.js is not loading, and i could imagine you are utilizing it within the controller, therefore unless and until you resolved your dependency, the issue persists

Comment: If you use Adblock check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318119/i-am-getting-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-blocked-by-client-with-google-chr and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341765/getting-neterr-blocked-by-client-error-on-some-ajax-calls

Comment: how can i resolved my dependcies

Comment: jus now i run in chrome ...no error is came but still got that blank page check my URL routing it is correct or not

Comment: now i got my abstract page but i cannot route the home.html page

Comment: Try `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");` or `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/event/home");`