# Getting the following error while trying to display image "blocked:other"

Tags: html, angular, image, google-chrome, ng-bootstrap

**Angular 6 ngBootstrap website**

[image]

(blocked:other)

The `better728x90.gif` exists in the correct folder, not sure why I'm gettin this error and other 404s on images that do exist.

The following path is correct:

```
<a href="assets/images/banners/better728x90.gif">
    <img src="assets/images/banners/better728x90.gif" width="728" height="90" class="fit"><br>
</a>
```

When I check out the img element in the chrome inspector I see this:

```
img[src="assets/images/banners/better728x90.gif"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

When I force all images to `display:block` with the following, the missing image icon finally shows up.

```
:host {
  img {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

---

```
assets/images/banners/better728x90.gif:1 GET http://localhost:4200/assets/images/banners/better728x90.gif net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Comment: Worth noting that adblocker is extremelly invasive nowadays: e.g. it blocks any image that ends in `_advertisement.jpg`, regardless of source!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

AH! It was my adBlocker!

[I am getting Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT with Google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318119/i-am-getting-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-blocked-by-client-with-google-chr)

I paused it on my local host and now the images are showing up.

Comment: Ditto! I was asked about a similar issue by my manager we had some segment.io calls being clocked.

Comment: why does this occur? Are image extensions considered ads and from when? Any further details would be welcome

Answer (score 1):

Note that AdBlockers can block images from loading based not just on the name of the image file (e.g.: `_advertisement.jpg`, `_ad.jpg`, `ad-1.jpg` etc.). I have found that AdBlockers will block images based on any of the following:

- The name of the directory containing the image file (e.g.: `/ad`, `/ad-1`, etc.).
- The name of the CSS class associated with the image (e.g.: `<img class="ad-img" ...`).

Renaming these elements to something that did not associate them with advertising fixed the issue.

Comment: I never thought of this. I really wondered why it works in different browser/people/pc, and also it doesn't work at some point. Thank you David for this precise information. What a change of me naming my filename _advertisement.jpg (where it really isn't an advertisement but a company name haha).