# How to use WebGrid in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to use WebGrid in ASP.NET Core (installed package `NonFactors.Grid.Mvc6` followed instructions from [link](http://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/Home/Installation)

```
 @(Html.Grid(Model).Build(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Add(model => model.FName).Titled("FistName");
                    })
                .Filterable()
                .Sortable()
                .Pageable()
        )
```

But running the code, the page shows blank, chrome-dev-tool: shows error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

suggestions, what can be done to fix it.
Thank you

Comment: the instructions for the MvcGrid is for non-Core.  I am looking for Core MvcGrid instructions..

Answer (score 0):

The error may occur when browser failed to download any resource file , check that in `Network` tab in F12 develop tools . Another possibility is resource blocked by one ad blocking plugin , you can click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390134/failed-to-load-resource-under-chrome) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318119/i-am-getting-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-blocked-by-client-with-google-chr/50151073#50151073) for more details .

Since the WebGrid resources(js,css files) are downloaded and add to your project , IMO WebGrid plugin won't cause the resource load error .

The problem is that data is not bind to WebGrid . According to [document](http://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/Home/Installation) , after installing the Nuget , you should copy the JS/css files to `wwwroot` folder , and reference them in your `_Layout.cshtml` , initialize MVC.Grid instances after rendering grid html as document shown .Also confirming you have sending the correct model lists to view form controller .