# Swagger TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I have problem when I call api for put and delete from swagger, error is:   `TypeError: Failed to fetch`

*Curl*

`curl -X DELETE "http://localhost:5000/api/Ad/2" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN"`

From setup I had enable cors like this and put on begin of ConfigureService method:

```
services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy(
        "AllowAll",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                          .AllowAnyMethod()
                          .AllowAnyHeader()
                          .AllowCredentials()
    );
});
```

thus from Configure before anything is put it
`app.UseCors("AllowAll");`

Why I'm not able to call delete method and put?

**Update 1**
[image]
[image]

Reagrds,
Danijel

Comment: What's the error message in the browser console?

Comment: dont want to ruing your day, but it looks like a known issue:
[github](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3969)

Comment: @Helen please check updates.

Comment: @PowerMouse your not ruing my day, I found also, cors are enabled and problem still present. Maybe I had enabled wrong ?

Comment: What is the error message in the **Console** tab of dev tools?

Comment: index.js:19 Could not find component JsonSchema_integer_int32
i @ index.js:19
:5000/api/Ad/2:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am getting Failed to load resource: net::ERR\_BLOCKED\_BY\_CLIENT with Google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318119/i-am-getting-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-blocked-by-client-with-google-chr)

Comment: Your correct AdBlock is blocking. Please manage answer

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `app.UseCors("AllowAll")` can you try `[EnableCors("AllowAll")]` on the controller endpoints? Also refer: [How to enable CORS in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31942037/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: I had removed app.UseCors("AllowAll") and put [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Member")]
    [EnableCors("AllowAll")]
    public class AdController : ControllerBase
Problem still present