# "ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT" error on XHR request (sentry.io, maps.googleapis.com) by uBlock Origin like ad-blockers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, sentry, adblock

Some of the XHR requests on my website is getting blocked by the uBlock origin adblocker it is throwing error like this

`GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/mapsjs/gen_204?csp_test=true net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

`POST https://o812912.ingest.sentry.io/api/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

Does anyone know how to fix this?
There are some open issues related to this but didn't find any perfect solution to the problem.

[uBlock issue](https://github.com/uBlockOrigin/uAssets/pull/7924)

[Sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/668)

Comment: You have a filter list in uBlock that blocks the given URL. Either add an exception or change your filter list subscriptions. If users of the site have the same problem they'd need to do the same. If you want to avoid it, you can probably proxy the requests through some domain you own.

Comment: @VLAZ Can you help me with how to proxy the requests through some domain?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found answer there
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318119/i-am-getting-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-blocked-by-client-with-google-chr/50151073#50151073