# Google Apps Script Docs Add-on sidebar is blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have created an add-on for Google Docs using Google App script. The add-on usually works fine, but if I try to run it in a Chrome browser account in which the Google account I'm using (G-Suit) is not the first on the list, the add-on sidebar will be blank when I try to open it.
In the console, I have the following errors:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
/offline/iframeapi?ouid=<censored (might not be sensitive info, not sure)>=5:1          GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:206          GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
So @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:206
(anonymous) @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:209
G @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:63
gp @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:209
fp @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:209
q.Oc @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:343
q.Tc @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:339
(anonymous) @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:185

3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:206          GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
So @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:206
(anonymous) @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:209
G @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:63
gp @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:209
fp @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:209
q.Nc @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:344
q.Tc @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:339
(anonymous) @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:185

3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:206          GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
So @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:206
(anonymous) @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:209
G @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:63
gp @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:209
fp @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:209
q.Oc @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:343
q.Tc @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:339
(anonymous) @ 3620742667-docs_offline_iframe_api_bin.js:185
22551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:58 Uncaught 
Sd @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:58
Yf @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:91
(anonymous) @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:24
eh.U @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:125
Jd @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:55
a @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:53

1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:3084          GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
Txd @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:3084
(anonymous) @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:3100
pz @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:433
Wyd @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:3100
Vyd @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:3100
oBk @ 382145908-client_js_prod_kix_tertiary.js:4308
jBk @ 382145908-client_js_prod_kix_tertiary.js:4308
(anonymous) @ 382145908-client_js_prod_kix_tertiary.js:4306
y.dispatchEvent @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:397
y.Xhb @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:3214
gYc @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:2197
eYc @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:2197
b @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:2478
(anonymous) @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:2695
a @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:2195

1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:3084          GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
Txd @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:3084
(anonymous) @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:3100
pz @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:433
Wyd @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:3100
Vyd @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:3100
oBk @ 382145908-client_js_prod_kix_tertiary.js:4308
jBk @ 382145908-client_js_prod_kix_tertiary.js:4308
(anonymous) @ 382145908-client_js_prod_kix_tertiary.js:4306
y.dispatchEvent @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:397
y.Xhb @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:3214
gYc @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:2197
eYc @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:2197
b @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:2478
(anonymous) @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:2695
a @ 1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:2195

1370409039-client_js_prod_kix_core.js:3084          GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:58 Uncaught 
Sd @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:58
Yf @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:91
(anonymous) @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:24
eh.U @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:125
Jd @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:55
a @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:53

2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:58 Uncaught 
Sd @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:58
Yf @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:91
(anonymous) @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:24
eh.U @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:125
Jd @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:55
a @ 2551766479-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user__iw.js:53
```

Worth noting that I don't have any extensions running, which would usually be the reason for those blocked by client errors.
I cannot post the code here, but I don't think it has anything to do with it, as all the errors (besides the last two) appear before I even try opening the sidebar using `Add-ons -> Add On Name -> Start`, and even when I don't have the Docs Add-on installed.
I was also able to reproduce it in Brave browser, and also sometimes when the Google Account I use is the only one in the browser account.
Any ideas what can cause this, and how can I fix it?

PS: the blank sidebar looks like this:[image]
instead of having some content in it.

Comment: Is there any point in your code where you make an HTTP request, have you tried starting Chrome in incognito or clearing the cache? Is it reproducible from multiple accounts? This seems more like a bug than a code error, I recommend you [open an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392207) on Google's Issuetacker.

Comment: Was able to reproduce on multiple accounts, cache cleaning and such does not help.

Comment: As you cannot post any code here, I strongly recommend opening an issue.

Comment: This is probably what I should do, yes. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, as the problem is reproducible from several accounts and browsers, the [most common solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318119/i-am-getting-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-blocked-by-client-with-google-chr) to this problem have been tested and no code can be provided to reproduce it, the best thing to do is to open a [new issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392207) in Google Issue Tracker, and try to get help from there.