# DevTools failed to load source map, ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Tags: devtools, source-maps

DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/scripts/iframe_form_check.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

i am expecting a error free console, i wanna run js in browser...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am getting Failed to load resource: net::ERR\_BLOCKED\_BY\_CLIENT with Google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318119/i-am-getting-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-blocked-by-client-with-google-chr)