# Chrome DevTools fails to load a WebExtension's source map with ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT (but I'm not using an ad blocker)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps, web-extension, web-ext

I'm developing a browser extension, **and for some reason Chrome will not load the source map for the extension's script.** This is the specific error:

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://kjfipmhmjjgociljdeefnicimgmmadei/content/index.js.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318119/i-am-getting-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-blocked-by-client-with-google-chr) because I'm not using an ad blocker. In fact, I'm not using any extensions except for the [`web-ext` reload manager](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/getting-started-with-web-ext/).

Here are some potentially relevant facts:

- I'm using Chrome 112.0.5615.86 on Windows 10.
- Firefox is able to use the same source map without issues.
- I am using [`web-ext`](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/getting-started-with-web-ext/) to build and serve a local copy of my extension on a dedicated browser profile.
- My build process uses ESBuild and TypeScript.
- I have source maps enabled.
- The Chrome build of this extension uses Manifest V3 (builds for some other browsers use V2).
- The issue occurs even in Incognito Mode.
- I can click on the URL given by the error message and view the source map in the browser just fine.
- When I view the minified code in the `Sources` tab, Chrome gives me a "Source map detected" notice.
- I *was* able to use source maps with Chrome last night. I don't know what I changed to break this.

Comment: content/index.js.map must be listed in web_accessible_resources.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'll be damned, that did it! Thank you. If you post that as a full answer, I'll accept it and give you the rep you deserve.