# Embedded google map throws net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT in chromium(Brave) browser

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome-extension, brave

I have simply embedded google maps `<iframe>` tag in `index.html` file and hosted via VS code extension(live-server) in chromium based(brave) browser. It shows an error

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/mapsjs/gen_204?csp_test=true net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Index.html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe
      src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3532.8031834368167!2d85.3199904754433!3d27.69247732614716!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x39eb195a08b6c09f%3A0xd8e71fb76f30976d!2sMaitighar%20Mandala!5e0!3m2!1sen!2snp!4v1711688211048!5m2!1sen!2snp"
      width="600"
      height="450"
      style="border: 0"
      allowfullscreen=""
      loading="lazy"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"
    ></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Tried resolving it looking at Stackoverflow 2014 questions, [Getting "net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT" error on some AJAX calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341765/getting-neterr-blocked-by-client-error-on-some-ajax-calls) and [I am getting Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT with Google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318119/i-am-getting-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-blocked-by-client-with-google-chr).

These discussion gives me an idea that the error arises due to ad-blocker extension. Since brave has in-built ad-blocking shield. I turned it OFF for `localhost` and it turned out no errors in console.

How to avoid these errors while embedding Google maps and YouTube videos?

Comment: An extension has its own chrome-extension://id URL, not localhost.

Comment: I mean to say, I turned OFF the shield for the particular site(localhost).

Comment: Your index.html is a part of an extension, so it has chrome-extension:// URL, which is not related to localhost. If it's your `action` popup you should open it by clicking the extension icon and not via a server.